# Copy and use json-config file in Docker ASP.NET Core webapplication

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, config, visual-studio-2019

**The setup**
In my solution folder, I have this file/folder-structure

Source
    docker-compose.yml
    .dockerignore
    paths.json
    Webproject
        //All web-project files (including DockerFile)
    AnotherWebproject
        //All web-project files (including DockerFile)

In my Visual Studio project, I've added the paths.json as a **linked** file and to include it in my image, I've set my csproj file (don't know if this is necessary...)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
 <PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Windows</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
  <UserSecretsId>8bcf6be2-9d06-4667-89f6-38f25af5dfbc</UserSecretsId>
  <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="..\paths.json" Link="paths.json">
   <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </Content>
 </ItemGroup>
 ...
</Project>
```

And my Dockerfile to:

```
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-nanoserver-1803 AS base
 WORKDIR /app
 EXPOSE 80
 EXPOSE 443

 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-nanoserver-1803 AS base
 WORKDIR /src
 COPY ["Webproject/Webproject.csproj", "Webproject/"]
 COPY "paths.json" "paths.json"
 RUN dotnet restore "Webproject/Webproject.csproj"
 COPY . .
 WORKDIR "/src/Webproject"
 RUN dotnet build "Webproject.csproj" -c Release -o /app

 FROM build AS publish
 RUN dotnet publish "Webproject.csproj" -c Release -o /app

 FROM base AS final
 WORKDIR /app
 COPY --from=publish /app .
 ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Webproject.dll"]
```

To use the file in my application, I use:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                var environment = context.HostingEnvironment;
                var folder = Path.Combine(environment.ContentRootPath);

                config.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(folder, "paths.json"), false);
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

I even tried to exclude it in my .dockerignore file:

```
 !paths.json
```

FYI... I'm using also a docker-compose project

**The error**
When starting up the application, I have this error:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The configuration file 'paths.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'C:\app\paths.json'.'

**The question**
I tried a lot of different paths in the Dockerfile to include it, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me with setting the correct path?
Also, I searched if it is possible to list all the files (to check if it's copied to the correct path), but it doesn't seem possible?

Comment: If some more information should be necessary, please let me know! I'll provide it as soon as possible

Comment: Where is your dockerfile?

Comment: It's in the Webproject folder

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your full dockerfile content and dockerfile path, try following steps below:

1. Folder Structure
2. Source

   - Dockerfile
   - paths.json
   - Webproject
3. Dockerfile

   ```
   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
   WORKDIR /app
   EXPOSE 80
   EXPOSE 443

   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
   WORKDIR /src
   COPY ["DockerFileCopy/DockerFileCopy.csproj", "DockerFileCopy/"]
   RUN dotnet restore "DockerFileCopy/DockerFileCopy.csproj"
   COPY . .
   WORKDIR "/src/DockerFileCopy"
   RUN dotnet build "DockerFileCopy.csproj" -c Release -o /app

   FROM build AS publish
   RUN dotnet publish "DockerFileCopy.csproj" -c Release -o /app

   FROM base AS final
   WORKDIR /app
   COPY --from=publish /app .
   ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerFileCopy.dll"]
   ```

   There is no need to copy the `paths.json` in docker command, the `RUN dotnet build` and `RUN dotnet publish` will not copy this file to the published folder
4. We use link file to copy the `paths.json`, the .csproj content

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

       <PropertyGroup>
           <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
           <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
           <UserSecretsId>2594cc66-3d1a-487b-a93c-99e0cf9975ef</UserSecretsId>
           <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
           <DockerfileContext>.</DockerfileContext>
       </PropertyGroup>
       <ItemGroup>
           <Content Include="..\paths.json" Link="paths.json">
           <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
           <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
           </Content>
       </ItemGroup>

       <ItemGroup>
           <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
           <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
           <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.7.9" />
       </ItemGroup>

   </Project>
   ```
5. Build the image in the Source folder by command like `docker build -t dockerfilecopy .`

Comment: Isn't this different because I use a docker-compose file?

Comment: Aren't the paths in the DockerFile relative to the docker-compose file, when present? (+ I'd rather keep my filestructure as above, since I have multiple webprojects and multiple DockerFiles)

Comment: @RubenHerman For dockerfile, you could not access the parent file from the dockerfile. The way to copy the file is controlled by `<Content Include="..\paths.json" Link="paths.json">`.